# How do i set a boolean to true or false instead of 1 or 0?

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a program that sets the index's of the "used" array to true or false depending on if there are characters in the "word" array.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  const int SIZE = 5;
  char word[SIZE] = {'H', 'e', 'l', '\0', '\0'};

  bool used[SIZE];

  cout << "word: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
     cout << " " << word[i];
  }

  cout << endl << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
      if (word[i] != '\0')
         used[i] = true;
      else
         used[i] = false;
   }

   cout << "used: ";
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      cout << " " << used[i];
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
word: H e l
used: 1 1 1 0 0
```

**My question is, can you store 'true' or 'false' in an array opposed to 1's and 0's?**

Comment: `<< std::boolalpha`

Comment: If you don't like `true` and `false` that `std::boolalpha` will provide, you can do your own too:  `cout << " " << (used[i] ? "T" : "F");`

Answer (score 0):

> How do i set a boolean to true or false

You can initialise for example:

```
bool variable = true;
```

---

You may be interested in how to output `"true"` or `"false"` when inserting a boolean into a output stream. The `std::boolalpha` I/O manipulator is for that purpose.